# Setting useState to value of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am trying to set the value of my state to be the value of the input.

```
<input
            placeholder="Username"
            onChange={(() => setUserName(value), console.log(userName))}
            type="text"
            value={userName}
></input>
```

When I do this I am getting the following error message:

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. 
This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Which leads me to a [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), however all of these examples are with class components and not functional ones. How can I accomplish this with a functional component?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. Sounds like you forgot to provide an initial value for the `userName`

Comment: Is `userName` set? And where is `value` coming from? Also, your onChange function doesn't look correct and is missing brackets.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: If `value` is undefined and then *becomes* defined, this is the error you will see. It seems `userName` is initially undefined. Controlled vs Uncontrolled inputs have nothing at all to do with class-based or functional components, or even stateful or stateless components, it's all about an input and its `value` or `defaultValue` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Especially for pointing out that my onChange was wrong, i wasn't even thinking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null);

<input
        placeholder="Username"
        onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        value={userName}>
</input>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this was my problem. Except I needed to set ```useState("")``` too

Answer (score -1):

Your state initialization should be something like:

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null);
```